# Is %HOMEDRIVE% valid in web.config?

Tags: iis

trying to add a handler to my web.config file, but using a windows variable doesn't work. How can I use %HOMEDRIVE% or something similar in the `scriptProcessor` attribute?

```xml
        <handlers>
            <remove name="PHP_via_FastCGI" />
            <add name="PHP_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="%HOMEDRIVE%\php\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
```

Comment: `HOSTDRIVE` is not a valid Windows environment variable, so it won't work automatically. If you set it as machine level and restart IIS, then it might work.

Comment: @LexLi sorry, meant `%HOMEDRIVE%`, edited

Comment: That is a predefined variable

Comment: Why not just use the traditional DOS path, `scriptProcessor="C:\php\php-cgi.exe"` instead of `scriptProcessor="%HOMEDRIVE%\php\php-cgi.exe"`?

Comment: @YurongDai this server is hosted on different machines with different configurations

Comment: What error are you getting? Set `Load User Profile` to true in the application pool advanced settings.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use `%SystemDrive%` variable instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/#configuration-sample